# how rails generation/migration etc distinguish with rails s environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm writing a rails server application which has some extra code needs to run,
like rufus-scheduler

```
block = proc do
  cache = CacheStatDaily.new
  cache.connect_terminals_count = Terminal.where {:last_connected_at.lt  }
  cache.save
end
scheduler.cron('0 0 * * *',&block)
```

to create some stats in everyday,(and some other code like every 2 hours)
but unfornately this code(and initializer code) gets run even I rails g model/
rails g migration/rake db:migrate etc, it seems the rails environment gets initialized
also in those commands,
but I need to distinguish with this differences and make sure that code do not run 
in wrong environment, 
how can I do this? Thanks.